# Case insensitive file search from s3 bucket

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am using the Spring Boot SDK for `aws` and I want to check my `s3` bucket to check if a file exists or not, ignoring the case of the filename. Right now I am searching if the file exits by:

```
s3client.doesObjectExist(bucketname,objectname)
```

`objectname` is the file key for `s3` with complete filename at the end. So, what I want to do is: if the file path is `a/b/c/d/car.pdf`, the above method should return "true," even though the actual file path in `s3` is: `a/b/c/d/CAR.pdf`, `a/b/c/d/caR.pdf` or `a/b/c/D/car.pdf`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ObjectListing listObjects(String bucketName) throws SdkClientException, AmazonServiceException
```

> Returns a list of summary information about the objects in the
>   specified buckets. List results are always returned in lexicographic
>   (alphabetical) order.
>
> Because buckets can contain a virtually unlimited number of keys, the
>   complete results of a list query can be extremely large. To manage
>   large result sets, Amazon S3 uses pagination to split them into
>   multiple responses. Always check the ObjectListing.isTruncated()
>   method to see if the returned listing is complete or if additional
>   calls are needed to get more results. Alternatively, use the
>   AmazonS3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(ObjectListing) method as an easy
>   way to get the next page of object listings.
>
> The total number of keys in a bucket doesn't substantially affect list
>   performance.

So, you can do something like this:

```
ObjectListing objectListing = s3client.listObjects("MyBucketName");
for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
    // implement some search algorithm to find matching files using objectSummary.getKey()
}
```

Comment: "The total number of keys in a bucket doesn't substantially affect list performance." , Is this tested ?, because for me it is taking some time.